# Properties of $f$ such that $f(x-1)-f(x+1)=\lfloor f(x)-f(x+1) \rfloor$

Tags: functions, periodic-functions

Let $f\colon\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ be such that $f(x-1)-f(x+1)=\lfloor f(x)-f(x+1) \rfloor$ for all $x$.
Then $f$ must be:

a) periodic

b) constant

c) discontinuous if nonconstant

---

I do not have an example of such a non-constant function.

My attempt: using $t-1<\lfloor t\rfloor\le t$ I obtained $f(x)-f(x+1)-1 < f(x-1)-f(x+1) \le f(x)-f(x+1)$ -- equivalent to $0\le f(x)-f(x-1)<1$.
This is for all $x$, so $x:=x+1$ gives $0\le f(x+1)-f(x)<1$ or $-1<f(x)-f(x+1)\le 0$. Hence $\lfloor f(x)-f(x+1) \rfloor$ is always $0$ or $-1$, so I have $f(x-1)-f(x+1)\in\{-1,0\}$ always, but now what?

Answer (score 4):

$f(x) = x/2$ is an example that is continuous and neither periodic nor constant.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Show that any $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ that is periodic with period $1$ has the desired property; that will give you continuous, non-constant examples.

Comment: fine! so now a) remains only

Comment: This post could be taken as saying it's (a)  as (b) and (c) are excluded. Or as it explains b,c yet leaves open a. It might make sense to clarify the intent.

Comment: Downvoted after non-reaction to the comment above.

Comment: @quid: I saw no reason to react to a fairly silly comment. The post clearly says that (b) and (c) are excluded and says nothing about (a). And the OP clearly understood this.

Comment: My point is that it does not become apparent, and this is also an issue with the question, whether it is intended as three yes/no answer or as a "pick the correct one."  I continue to think that in combination with your by now deleted reply to OP this post can be confusing. (Though admittedly not to OP as they knew how the question was intended.) It was confusing to me. Given the other answer it's not that important. Yet to address the perceived issue would have been as trivial as adding a "(for b and c)" after your HINT.

Comment: Specifically "now a) remains only"  can be read as "remains as valid reply" or as "remains to be addressed." Your reply, "genau!" IIRC, which I'd understand as an enthusiastic confirmation, rather suggests a reply to the former than to the latter.